# A compact Kähler manifold X with $H^{1,1}(X; \mathbb Z)=0$ cannot be embedded in a projective space?

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Why is it impossible to embed a compact Kähler manifold X with $H^{1,1}(X; \mathbb Z)=0$ in a projective space?

I suspect this can be shown using the Lefschetz theorem on (1,1)-classes, but I don't see how.

Comment: What does $H^{1,1}(X; \mathbb Z)$ mean?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  It is defined in Huybrecht's book on page 133 directly before the (1,1)-theorem. If I understood it right, we think of $H^2(X;\mathbb Z)\subset H^2(X;\mathbb C)$, as the forms which take integer values when evaluated on the generators of $H_2(X,\mathbb Z)$. Afterwards we project (the representatives) to $H^{1,1}(X)$, the forms of type $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that $X$ is compact and that by $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)=0$ you mean $H^{1,1}(X)=0$: if $X\subset\mathbb CP^N$ and if $\omega\in\Omega^{1,1}(\mathbb CP^N)$ is the (Fubini-Study) symplectic form, then $\omega$ is a symplectic form also on $X$ (it is non-degenerate on $X$ as it is the imaginary of the Fubini-Study hermitian metric), and thus the cohomology class of $\omega$ gives you a non-zero element of $H^{1,1}(X)$.

Comment: I didn't mean $H^{1,1}(X)=0$. I encountered this statement as a tool to show that a Kähler manifold is not projective. 

(I edited my question accordingly)

Comment: For the meaning of $H^{1,1}$ see my comment below the question.

Comment: @klirk - I see; but certainly $[\omega]\in H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$, as it is the pullback of $[\omega]\in H^{1,1}(\mathbb CP^N,\mathbb Z)$, so it's enough to show that $[\omega]\neq 0\in H^{1,1}(X)$

Comment: Did I understood you right; does your argument something like this? Assume for contradiction that $X$ is projective. We can find an element of $H^{1,1}(\mathbb CP^n,\mathbb Z)$. As $H_2(\mathbb CP^n,\mathbb Z)$ only has one generator we can simply scale the Kähler form to get a form which has integer values when evaluated on the generator. (Or does the Kähler form already do the job?). Then we take the pull-back of this form, i.e. we restrict it to $X$. But why is this then in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$? Isn't the homology of $X$ possibly much more complicated than the homology of $\mathbb CP^n$.

Comment: @klirk - yes that's what I meant (including the scaling) - and while the homology of $X$ might be complicated, the pairing with $[\omega]$ can be done via mapping the homology of $X$ to the homology of $\mathbb CP^n$ (and then pairing with $[\omega]$)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you